# Using decltype for lambda comparators

Tags: c++, lambda, decltype

I'm trying to understand the difference in the following two cases.
In both, I introduce a comparator as a lambda function:

`auto comp = [](int x, int y) { return x%2 < y%2; };`

But then, if I want to use it with a sort, I can simply write

`sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);`

while for a class templated on a comparator, e.g. a priority_queue I need a wrapper:

`priority_queue<int, decltype(comp)> my_queue;`

to pass it as a template parameter.

The sort function itself is templated on a comparator class, yet it's somehow works without a decltype. Is there an implicit conversion that works for a `sort`, but doesn't work in the second case?

Comment: The things inside of `<>` are types, and the things inside of `()` are instances of types

Comment: `sort(..., comp);` takes an *instance* of a comparator as an input parameter. `comp` is an object instance, whose *type* is defined by the compiler. Whereas `priority_queue<..., decltype(comp)>` takes a *type* of a comparator as a template argument. You can't pass an object instance in a template, but you can pass its type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction).  The overload of `std::sort` that you are calling is declared as

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

and when you call it like

```
sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);
```

The compiler goes through the template argument deduction steps to determine what `RandomIt` and `Compare` are based of the types of the variables passed to the function.

In the case of your `priority_queue` you don't get this because there are no variables to deduce types from.  Because of that you have to specify the template arguments yourself.

That said, starting in C++17 we now have [class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) and we can use the argument supplied to the constructor to deduce the template parameters of the class.  For instance if you want your `priority_queue` to use a `std::vector<int>` as the underlying container and keep the order using `comp` then you can do that with

```
priority_queue my_queue(comp, std:vector<int>{});
```